# How to edit LD_LIBRARY_PATH?

Tags: objective-c, gnustep

Unfortunately, I'm having trouble compiling the GNUstep Startup package. This requires an edit in the LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable which I'm unfamiliar with. Some reading up on it didn't quite tell me what I would need to do to implement a particular solution for this. Is there anyone who knows what this means exactly? The message is a little cryptic to me.

```
I don't seem to be able to use your Objective-C compiler to produce
working binaries!  Please check your Objective-C compiler installation.
For gcc-3.0.x make sure that your compiler's libgcc_s and libobjc
can be found by the dynamic linker - usually that requires you to add
the directory given by gcc -print-file-name=libobjc.so to your
LD_LIBRARY_PATH or /etc/ld.so.conf.
Please refer to your compiler installation instructions for more help.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/what/you/want
```

Comment: if I load that in my .bashrc, will that automate the process?

Comment: it may screwup building other projects, sometimes its better to put it before the command thats using it, i.e. LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/ ld ... and it won't affect anything else